# Is there a way to increase the maximum 10 GB size limit of SQL Express?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

Is there a way to increase the maximum 10 GB size limit of SQL Express?

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx

[image]

Comment: yes... by upgrading to a full license ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server **2008 R2** Express has a **10 GB** size limit.

For details, see:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/Default.aspx

Comment: @mokokamello: if 10 GB for Express aren't good enough, you need a full license - no other way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

> Thank you for your feedback. The
>   limitations on SQL Express are suited
>   to the primary target users of the
>   product, who typically don't need to
>   store significant amounts of data. At
>   this point we are planning to continue
>   the 4 GB database size limit for SQL
>   Express 2008.
>
> Given that the bulk of your file size
>   is the result of storing blobs, you
>   should take a look at a new feature
>   being introduced in SQL 2008 called
>   Filestream Data. This feature allows
>   for the storage of blobs directly on
>   the NT file system while tracking them
>   from within the database. A bit more
>   can be read about this feature in the
>   SQL 2008 Product Overview available
>   from
>   http://www.microsoft.com/sql/techinfo/whitepapers/sql2008Overview.mspx.
>   This feature will be included in SQL
>   Express and should significantly
>   reduce the size of your file while
>   giving you the flexibility to track
>   your blobs in the database.
>
> Regards, Mike Wachal SQL Server
>   Express team

Found @ [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/257501/increase-4gb-limit-to-sql-express)

Answer (score 2):

No, you would have to purchase a [full SQL Server license](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/pricing.aspx) to store more data.

Comment: Or, for personal use, the [Developer Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/developer.aspx) may be an option.

Comment: The Developer Edition seems to be the best answer, thanks! https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads